# Is there a way to do (A*B) mod M without overflow for unsigned long long A and B?

Tags: c++, numbers, overflow

I don't want the nightmare of installing GMP on Windows.

I have two numbers A and B, `unsigned long long`s, on the order of magnitude 10^10 or so at most, but even when doing `((A%M)*(B%M))%M`, I get integer overflow.

Are there homebrew functions for calculating `(A*B)%M` for larger numbers?

Comment: What is the order of magnitude of M?

Comment: basically M*M overflows?

Comment: Yes, pretty much. Sample numbers: 9030460994 x 9030460994 mod 12*10^9 => overflow

Comment: I can think of a way (but not quite efficient) by using congruence recursively. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congruence_relation

Comment: You can also do this very easily with OpenSSL with the various `BN_*_word` functions.

Comment: Also, .Net has a `BigInteger` class.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the modulus `M` is sufficiently smaller than `ULLONG_MAX` (which is the case if it's in the region of 10^10), you can do it in three steps by splitting one of the factors in two parts. I assume that `A < M` and `B < M`, and `M < 2^42`.

```
// split A into to parts
unsigned long long a1 = (A >> 21), a2 = A & ((1ull << 21) - 1);
unsigned long long temp = (a1 * B) % M;   // doesn't overflow under the assumptions
temp = (temp << 21) % M;                  // this neither
temp += (a2*B) % M;                       // nor this
return temp % M;
```

For larger values, you can split the factor in three parts, but if the modulus becomes really close to `ULLONG_MAX` it becomes ugly.