# Computing pow(a, b) % n where b and n are large uint64_t

Tags: c, math, long-integer

I'm playing around with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test

I want to test if a `uint64_t` is prime or not. For that I need to compute `pow(a, b) % n` where `a <= 37` but `b` and `n` can be large `uint64_t` values. I know I can compute `pow(a, b)` with the square-and-multiply algorithm doing `% n` in every step. But that still leaves 2 problematic operations: `(x * x) % n` and `(x * a) % n`.

I wonder if there is something better than splitting everything into low and high 32bit and doing long multiplication and long division for the remainder.

PS: don't assume there is a 128bit integer type

Comment: No, there's not really anything significantly better if you don't have a 128-bit type.

Comment: How does this question differ from existing ones, e.g.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10076011/calculate-aa-mod-n-without-overflow, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28259832/how-can-i-avoid-overflow-in-modular-multiplication, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13464745/is-there-a-way-to-do-ab-mod-m-without-overflow-for-unsigned-long-long-a-and-b, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45918104/how-to-do-arithmetic-modulo-another-number-without-overflow

Comment: And another is [Ways to do modulo multiplication with primitive types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12168348/ways-to-do-modulo-multiplication-with-primitive-types) although it's tagged C++.

Comment: @njuffa it doesn't, I'm just bad at searching. But lets see: 10076011 does 64 shift+addmod for a multiplication, surely we can do better. 28259832 has no correct answer. 13464745 overflows for large n. 45918104 is rust and again 64 shifts + addmod. And Weather Vane's link again does 64 shifts+addmod or worse 2^64 addmods. So yeah, it's a duplicate but there is nothing I would call a solution.

Comment: If you're using gcc on x86_64, you can use inline asm with the `mul` and `div` instructions to store the intermediate 128 bit value in the rdx:rax pair, but that it very target specific.

Comment: @ChrisDodd I tried __int128 on x86_64, which gets the `mul` right but doesn't use the `div`: https://godbolt.org/z/19esKx9x3

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk https://godbolt.org/z/f4oondfMx sqrmod is with 128-bit type, sqrmod2 is what I think the code should be. But ARM doesn't have __int128 anyway.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow: yes, you need to use inline asm to use the rdx:rax pair: `asm("mul %2; div %3" : "+a"(a), "+d"(r) : "r"(b), "r"(m));` will compute r = (a*b)%m; (and incidentally clobber a, but its tough to avoid that -- the "clobber" spec is not useful for avoiding that problem as there are two instructions here and the clobber happens in the middle.)

Comment: @Useless 1) this does up to 64 or `1<<64 - 1` additions depending on which answer. Have fun waiting for the later to finish. 2) It overflows for values over `1 << 63`. So no, that doesn't answer the question.